# bounce with marquee makes text not fully visible

Tags: html, css

I have a css bounce-effect in combination with a  tag (the code is for a somewhat not-so-serious chat) and it makes the text not fully visible when bouncing.

Here's an example of the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/ohkgqy13/1/

Here's the CSS:

```
bounce {
    display: inline-block;
    animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}

.container {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <marquee><bounce>ASDF</bounce></marquee>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: reduce the bounce effect? add some padding,margin?

Comment: In this simple example I guess it could be done, but in the real code there's no way of knowing how large the <div> element will be. Sorry for not clarifying that.

Comment: you can still have full control ... if you translate with 15px and you have 15px of padding then your are sure it will be always visible

Comment: That's true. But I don't want to have 15px of padding on every row of these divs (it's a chat and each post is a div). I'd like to just expand the div when it contains a <marquee> and <bounce>-tag.

I guess I could pull that off with some JS, but if it's possible to just solve with some CSS I'd prefer that.

Comment: I solved it with adding this <bounce style="margin-top: 15px"> through some JS, when the margin was needed.

Answer (score 0):

The text is overflowing its container. Increase the line-height so that there is more space before it overflows itself. You can always change the top margin to counter it if you need it higher.

```
<div class="container" style="line-height: 60px; margin-top: -5px;">
<marquee><bounce>ASDF</bounce></marquee>
</div>

bounce {
    display: inline-block;
    animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
}

.container {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this could do the trick but I found out that adding this on the <bounce>-element worked very well: <bounce style="margin-top: 15px;">ASDF</bounce>